# what version of cordova is used in worklight 6.2.0.1? Does the latest ifix provides 64bit support for iOS hybrid applications?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

We are creating a hybrid application using Worklight. We need to use version 6.2.0.1 Consumer edition. Does interim fix: 6.2.0.1-WCE-IF201502141613 provide 64-bit support for hybrid applications? What is the Cordova library version that we get with this iFix?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/ibm_worklight_platform_and_ios_64_bit_support?lang=en see this blog for your query regarding 64 bit support

Comment: To check the cordova version it better you see in your android environment built. The **cordova,js** file present in the environment  will help you with the version info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight 6.2 is shipped with Cordova v3.4.1.
It doesn't matter which iFix of 6.2 you're using, it's still Cordova 3.4 (with patches in case of bugs).

However this does not matter - all Worklight releases received an iFix release for 64bit support for iOS.

See [this blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2014/12/17/ios-64-bit-support/) for more information.
What you need to do is to go to IBM Fix Central website and download the latest available iFix for your version of Worklight. That is all.

The iFix version you've mentioned is from 2015, well *after* the support was added. Still, it is best to download the latest iFix in case there is one newer than the one mentioned.

Comment: Hi Idan,the one which I mentioned above is the latest in IBM iFix central, couldn't find the newer one. Below is the URL where i am looking for iFix's.  http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm%7EOther%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+Worklight+Consumer+Edition&release=6.2.0.1&platform=Windows&function=all

Comment: Thanks idan for the info.